# How to make an Android horizontal LinearLayout with children that have a percentage width?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I've been searching this for a while and can't seem to quite grasp it. I know that this is probably done by using `android:layout_weight`, but I can't seem to figure it out.

What I want to accomplish is to have a horizontal LinearLayout that stretches the width of its parent's container and wraps the height of its child views. This will be used for a music player for my app. For the child views, I want the following...

Four ImageViews in a row, each set to 15% of the width (previous button, play/pause button, next button, and playlist button). Then after these, I will have some type of view to represent the progress of the song you are listening to which will fill the remaining width (obviously 40% of the width).

My icons will be square, and I need the progress bar to be the same height as the icons. Below is a screenshot from my mobile site, and you can see what I'm trying to recreate by looking at the footer of the site.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this... total weightSum of 100, and you can make the desired distribution

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal" 
   android:weightSum="100">

   BUTTON 1 layout_weight=15
   BUTTON 2 layout_weight=15
   BUTTON 3 layout_weight=15
   BUTTON 4 layout_weight=15

   ProgressBar layout_weight=40

</LinearLayout>
```

Also you can check this link about weight distribution  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

Comment: `android:weightSum` made it easier. Not sure where I was having problems before, but this seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: if you post your XML code we could find the error, but keep using weightSum its really easy to use... can you mark as an answer i need reputation score... tnx